Normal Distribution where $-0.2<x_1-y_i<0.3$ for $i\in \{1,2,\dots,5\}$.
I am having difficulties solving the following problem on normal distribution:
The normal random variable $X$ has a mean of $3.5$ and standard deviation of $0.2$.
The normal random variable $Y$ has a mean of $3.3$ and standard deviation of $0.1$.
We call $(x,y)$ nice if $-0.2<x-y<0.3$. 
Suppose an $X$ is randomly chosen, denote it by $x_1$. Suppose five $Y$s' are randomly chosen, denote them by $y_1,y_2,\dots,y_5$. 
What is the probability that $(x_1,y_1), \dots , (x_1,y_5)$ are all nice?
I attempted to treat each $x_1-y_i$ as independent and calculate $P(\{-0.3<X-Y<0.2\})^5$. That would have worked if I had $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2),...,(x_5,y_5)$. But, clearly each pair is not independent as the $x$ value is the same.

Since $x_1$ is fixed, just consider the event "$y$ is in the nice band about $x_1$" for each $y_i$.  Those are independent.

So doing something like $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-3.5}{0.2}\right)^2}}{0.2\sqrt{2\pi}} \left(P(-0.2<x-Y<0.3)\right)^5 dx$ would be right?

Exactly.  $\quad$
